# Questions about hyper-plane tangent to a point on a surface

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am quite confused with the tangent of a hyperplane to a point. My question is why it consider $\lim_{x\to x_0} |x-x_0|^{-1}||z'-z|=0$instead of just $\lim_{x\to x_0}|z'-z|=0$ and why would it be $0$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any sense of the expression "the tangent of a hyperplane to a point"; I'll assume that it's meant to refer to what you correctly refer to as the "hyperplane tangent to a point on a surface" in the title.

Your version of the condition would be satisfied whenever the plane intersects the surface at $\mathbf x$. A tangent plane is meant to do more than just intersect. The English word *tangent* is derived from the present participle *tangens* of the Latin verb *tangere*, to touch. The tangent touches the surface in the sense that it coincides with the surface not only at $\mathbf x$ but also to first order in its vicinity. This is what's expressed by the condition in the text.